# Scroll to Row with Pageable option in a List grid Smart gwt

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I have a list grid which contains thousands of records. I can update any row in this list grid. After updating a row, I need to remain focus to the particular row. 
From the `RecordClickEvent`, I take the index of the record. When I fetch the data again I've used below methods.

```
listGrid.selectRecord(recordIndex);
listGrid.scrollToRow(recordIndex);
```

If I update a record within first 75, it works nicely. How can I remain the focus, if I update a record not in first 75 records?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No, I don't solve it yet

Comment: One thing that works pretty well in my case is to come up with a simple test case were I can reproduce the problem. Have you tried that? If so, post your code here so that I can take a look and help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You must be doing something in your code that breaks this default behavior (of keeping focus on the edited record), because I have a paged editable `ListGrid` with close to 20.000 records, and when I update any record, I retain focus on the edited record without doing anything specific. Without looking at your code, it's not possible to know what can be wrong in your case, that focus is lost after updating one record.

Take a look at [this](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_frozen_editing) particular demo for an example of what I mean regarding the default behavior.

By the way, what you are trying to do could be accomplished by loading your data page by page, until you get past the recordIndex, but take into consideration that this could be a very disconcerting user experience.